# pyqtgraph plot multiple QPainterPath that look like pg.TextItem

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

This is what it looks when you add pg.TextItems to each individual pg.ScatterPlotItem

[image]

using:

```
label = pg.TextItem(text=str(i), color=HEX_ORANGE, anchor=([1, 1]))
label.setPos(x, y)
self.plot.addItem(label)
```

but this can only be done in a for loop and that is slow... so i wanted to replace it with a faster solution. I found that replacing it with QPainterPath works for pg.ScatterPlotItem but i cannot get them to behave the same using:

```
from PySide6.QtGui import QTransform, QPainterPath, QFont


def genSymbol(label):
    # Basically the example in pyqtgraph/examples/ScatterPlotItem
    symbol = QPainterPath()
    f = QFont()
    f.setPointSize(5)
    symbol.addText(0, 0, f, label)
    br = symbol.boundingRect()
    scale = min(1. / br.width(), 1. / br.height())
    tr = QTransform()
    tr.scale(scale, scale)
    tr.translate(-br.x() - br.width()/2., -br.y() - br.height()/2.)
    return symbol


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import pyqtgraph as pg
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
    from PySide6.QtGui import QColor

    app = pg.mkQApp("PerPlotHelper")
    w = QMainWindow()
    cw = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
    w.show()
    w.resize(600, 600)
    w.setCentralWidget(cw)
    w.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Arrow')
    p = cw.addPlot(row=0, col=0)
    ####
    point_xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    point_ys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

    points = pg.ScatterPlotItem(point_xs, point_ys,
                                symbol='o',
                                size=9,
                                pen=pg.mkPen(QColor("#ff9900")),
                                brush=pg.mkBrush(QColor("#ff9900")),
                                data="w/e")
    p.addItem(points)
    symbols = [genSymbol(str(i)) for i in range(len(point_xs))]
    # Draw Text Label
    spots = [{'x': point_xs[i],
              'y': point_ys[i],
              'data': "w/e",
              'brush': "#ff9900",
              'symbol': symbols[i]} for i in range(len(point_xs))]
    textLabelsP = pg.ScatterPlotItem(pen=pg.mkPen('w'), pxMode=True)
    textLabelsP.addPoints(spots)
    p.addItem(textLabelsP)

    app.exec()
```

only puts small, barely visible text on the top-right inside the point itself...

[image]

or with pxMode=False it produces this abomination:

[image]

What am i missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A symbol of the `ScatterPlotItem` is designed to be clipped by a rectangle of (x=-0.5, y=-0.5, width=1, height=1), where (x=0, y=0) means the center of the corresponding data point and the coordinates are scaled by the `size` option.

For your toy example, you can do like this, although it's useless.

```
...
def genSymbol(label):
    symbol = QPainterPath()
    f = QFont()
    f.setPixelSize(1)
    symbol.addText(-0.5, 0.5, f, label)
    return symbol
...
if ...
    ...
    spots = [{'x': point_xs[i],
              'y': point_ys[i],
              'size': 10, # The default value is 7 but it's too small.
              'data': "w/e",
              'brush': "#ff9900",
              'symbol': symbols[i]} for i in range(len(point_xs))]
    ...
...
```